# Theme.applyStyle() does not work after AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme

If I set `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)` when the system is dark in Android 12+ with dynamic colors enabled (cannot reproduce with dynamic colors disabled), `Theme.applyStyle(, force = true)` has no effect until I manually recreate the activity.

Sample code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ColorPatchUtils.setTheme(R.styles.MyPartialTheme, true)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known bug, which does not appear to have been fixed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123835106